# Como fazer tradução dos campos de um json?

Tags: javascript, json

Preciso fazer uma tradução dos campos de um json. Desejo informar como entrada um json multidimensional e como saída receber outro json com campos diferentes, porém permanecendo os valores.

Exemplo entrada:

```js
{
  "nome": [
     {
       "sobrenome": "Potter",
       "primeiro_nome": [
          "Harry"
        ]
     }
  ],
  "sexo": "masculino",
  "nascimento": "1992-05-26"
}
```

Exemplo saída:

```js
{
  "name": [
     {
       "family": "Potter",
       "given": [
          "Harry"
        ]
     }
  ],
  "gender": "masculino",
  "birthDate": "1992-05-26"
}
```

Para resolver o problema, inicalmente pensei em gerar um registro de relacionamento de campos para gerar a tradução (esse registro pretendo guardar em um banco de dados e usar para realizar a tradução).

Exemplo:

```js
inbound               => outbund
nome[0].sobrenome     => name[0].family
nome[1].primeiro_nome => name[1].given[0]
sexo                  => gender
nascimento            => birthDate
```

A minha dúvida está em como ler esse inbound e outbound e gerar o json de saída comforme especificado acima.

Gostaria de saber por gentileza, como vocês resolveriam este problema, gostaria de algumas ideias. Se ficou confuso, posso melhorar a questão para um melhor entendimento.

Answer (score 0):

então você quer traduzir as chaves de um json, um loop em todas as chaves pode resolver isso, você pode ir substituindo as chaves pelos respectivos valores traduzidos, ex:

```
// minha chave/valor da tradução
const traducao = {
    nome: "name",
    sobrenome: "family"
}

const json = {
    nome: [
        {
            sobrenome: "Potter"
        }
    ]
}

function keyTranslate(obj) {
    let res

    if (typeof(obj) != 'object') {
        return obj
    }

    res = Array.isArray(obj) ? [] : {}

    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        let k = traducao[key] || key
        res[k] = keyTranslate(obj[key])
    })
    
    return res
}

//
const meuJsonTraduzido = keyTranslate(json)
```

é claro que você pode melhorar esse código como poer exemplo passar o json de tradução para a função

Comment: Valeu @Dev RR Nogueira, estou aplicando aqui sua solução para ver o que sai.